# Forecast fetcher

Tags: java

I wrote a simple application that uses some weather api.
It has got 2 options.
It can fetch current forecast or it can fetch forecast for some days ahead.

I have used `ObjectMapper` to map `HttpResponse<JsonNode>` to my customized model objects.
I have been struggled with improving method that creates query for given host as only city is mandatory field, but if other fields (for example lang, units) will exist then they should be considered.

Service:

```
package weatherapp;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import weatherapp.model.currentforecastmodel.CurrentForecast;
import weatherapp.model.futureforecastmodel.FutureForecast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

@Service
public class ForecastService {

    private static final String X_RAPID_HOST = "community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com";
    private static final String X_RAPID_API_KEY = "...";
    private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";
    private static final String CURRENT_FORECAST_HOST = "https://community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com/weather";
    private static final String FORECAST_FOR_DAYS_AHEAD_HOST = "https://community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com/forecast/daily";
    private static final String NUMBER_OF_DAYS_AHEAD_QUERY = "cnt=%s";
    private static final String CITY_QUERY = "q=%s";
    private static final String LANGUAGE_AND_CITY_QUERY = "lang=%s&q=%s";
    private static final String UNITS_AND_CITY_QUERY = "units=%s&q=%s";

    public CurrentForecast getCurrentForecast(String city, String lang, String units) throws UnirestException, IOException {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = getJsonResponseFromUrl(city, lang, units, null,
                CURRENT_FORECAST_HOST);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody().toString(), CurrentForecast.class);

    }

    public FutureForecast getForecastForDaysAhead(String city, String language, String units, Integer numberOfDaysAhead)
            throws UnirestException, IOException {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = getJsonResponseFromUrl(city, language, units, numberOfDaysAhead,
                FORECAST_FOR_DAYS_AHEAD_HOST);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

        return objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody().toString(), FutureForecast.class);
    }

    private HttpResponse<JsonNode> getJsonResponseFromUrl(String city, String language, String units, Integer numberOfDaysForFutureForecast, String hostUrl)
            throws IOException, UnirestException {

        String query = getQueryAccordingToGivenParameters(city, language, units, numberOfDaysForFutureForecast);

        return Unirest.get(hostUrl + "?" + query)
                .header("x-rapidapi-host", X_RAPID_HOST)
                .header("x-rapidapi-key", X_RAPID_API_KEY)
                .asJson();
    }

    private String getQueryAccordingToGivenParameters(String city, String language, String units, Integer numberOfDaysAhead)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String query;
        if (language == null && units != null) {
            query = String.format(UNITS_AND_CITY_QUERY,
                    URLEncoder.encode(units, CHARSET),
                    URLEncoder.encode(city, CHARSET));
        } else if (language != null && units == null) {
            query = String.format(LANGUAGE_AND_CITY_QUERY,
                    URLEncoder.encode(language, CHARSET),
                    URLEncoder.encode(city, CHARSET));
        } else {
            query = String.format(CITY_QUERY,
                    URLEncoder.encode(city, CHARSET));
        }

        //only for days ahead
        if (numberOfDaysAhead != null) {
            String newQuery = String.format(NUMBER_OF_DAYS_AHEAD_QUERY,
                    URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(numberOfDaysAhead), CHARSET));
            return new StringBuilder(query).insert(0, newQuery).toString();
        }

        return query;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package weatherapp.controller;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import weatherapp.ForecastService;
import weatherapp.model.currentforecastmodel.CurrentForecast;
import weatherapp.model.futureforecastmodel.FutureForecast;

import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
public class ForecastController {

    private final ForecastService forecastService;

    @Autowired
    public ForecastController(ForecastService forecastService) {
        this.forecastService = forecastService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/forecast")
    public CurrentForecast getCurrentWeather(@RequestParam String city, @RequestParam(required = false) String lang,
                                             @RequestParam(required = false) String units)
            throws UnirestException, IOException {

        return forecastService.getCurrentForecast(city, lang, units);
    }

    @GetMapping("/future/forecast")
    public FutureForecast getForecastForDays(@RequestParam String city, @RequestParam(required = false) String lang,
                                             @RequestParam(required = false) String units,
                                             @RequestParam(required = false) Integer numberOfDaysAhead)
            throws UnirestException, IOException {

        return forecastService.getForecastForDaysAhead(city, lang, units, numberOfDaysAhead);
    }
}
```

Model classes are in my gh repository: https://github.com/must1/test

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so basically what you have is a set of key-value pairs (query param name and value) where the value may be specified or not and the end result is a String concatenation of the pairs.

this is a classic case for `Map<String, String>`

I would convert of all the `_QUERY` constants to have the names of the query params, then I would populate the map with the (possibly null) arguments:

```
private static final String NUMBER_OF_DAYS_AHEAD_QUERY = "cnt";
private static final String CITY_QUERY = "q";
...

private Map<String, String> queryMap = new HashMap<>();

private void initQueryMap(String city, String language, String units, Integer numberOfDaysAhead) {
    queryMap.put(CITY_QUERY, city);
    queryMap.put(NUMBER_OF_DAYS_AHEAD_QUERY, String.valueOf(numberOfDaysAhead));
    ...
}
```

now it is a simple matter of iterating over the map entries, filtering non-null values and producing the "key=value" string pattern. it is easily achievable with stream processing. I will leave that to you.

**EDIT**

Here's how to create a query string from the map:

```
    String queryStr = queryMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(ent -> ent.getValue() != null)
        .map(ent -> ent.getKey() + "=" + ent.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
```

Comment: I have made it like this: https://pastebin.com/AgizaF6g Good?

Comment: it can be done with stream processing with greater ease and clarity